# Ring $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_{3} = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ the ring of integer modulo $3$. We consider the ensemble $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{F}[i]$ with elements of the form $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$. We define the sum and the product as : $$(a_1 +b_1 i) + (a_2 +b_2 i) = (a_1 + a_2) + (b_1 + b_2)i$$ and $$(a_1 +b_1 i) \cdot (a_2 +b_2 i) = (a_1 a_2 - b_1 b_2) + (a_1 b_2 + a_2b_1)i$$ In other words, we suppose that $i^{2} = -1$ for all $a + bi \in \mathbb{K}$ and we consider the norm $$N(a+bi) = (a+bi)(a-bi)=a^{2} +b^{2}$$

1. Verify that we have a ring
2. Verify that the equation $x^{2} = -1$ doesn't have a solution in $\mathbb{F}_3$. Conclude that $a+bi = 0$ if and only if $a=0$ and $b=0$ and that $N(a+bi) = 0$ if and only if $a+bi = 0$
3. Show that for all  $a+bi \neq 0$, we have $N(a+bi)$ invertible in $\mathbb{F}_3$

I did the first question but I am not sure about the question 2 and 3.
For the question 2, I have been able to show that the equation $x^{2} = -1$ did't have a solution in $\mathbb{F}_3$, but I am not sure about the conclusion part, here is what I did :

To show that $a+bi = 0\implies a = 0 \text{ and } b= 0$, I have sarted with $a+bi = 0 \implies \frac{-a}{b} = i$, but because we have shown that there does not exist an element $x\in \mathbb{K}$ such that $x^{2} = -1$, we know that $i \notin \mathbb{K}$. But at this point I don't see how I will end with $a = 0$ and $b = 0$.

Also for the other side , $a = 0 \text{ and } b= 0 \implies a+bi = 0$, can we just substitute $a$ and $b$ by $0$ as this $a+bi = 0+0i = 0$ ?

Now to show that $N(a+bi) = 0$ if and only if $a+bi = 0$. If $a+bi = 0$ then $N(a+bi) = 0$ : By the difinition of the norm $N(a+bi) = (a+bi)(a-bi)= 0(a - bi) = 0$. I am not sure about the last equality, do we need the ring to be an integral domain ?

If $N(a+bi) = 0$ then $a+bi = 0$ : $N(a+bi) = 0 \implies (a+bi)(a-bi)= 0\implies (a+bi) = 0 or? (a-bi) = 0$ here I am not sure if there is a way to show that the case $(a-bi) \neq 0$.

For the question 3, I didn't have a precise idea to solve the problem.

I would like to know if what I have written is correct.
Also, I would appreciate if you could inform me if my approach is good or if there is something that I should revise or change.

Comment: You could write $\frac{-a}{b}=i$ if you **assume** $b\neq 0$, which can be used to build a contradiction here. Also, you could prove that $\mathbb{F}_3$ is an integral domain ($\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field for $p$ prime), though I think you can bash out the second part of Problem 2. For Q3, if $a+bi\neq 0$ we have $N(a+bi)\neq 0$. Thus, we must have some inverse of the norm in $\mathbb{F}_3$. Considering all this, it might be much more convenient if you prove that $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a field.

Comment: But for the question 2, part 2, if I prove that $\F_3$ is an integral domain, am I going to use this argument for both sides of each implication ?

Comment: I don't think you have to generalize in this case. You can just bash it out as Stahl did. You don't really need to consider the backward implication in this case since it's super trivial. You just need to prove that if $N(a+bi)=0$ then $a=b=0$, which can be done by a contrapositive argument.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, you're on the right track. If $a + bi = 0$ and $b\neq 0,$ this would imply the existence of $i\in\Bbb{F}_3$ such that $i^2 = -1.$ This cannot be, so we must have $b = 0.$ But if this is true, then $a + bi = a$ and so $a + bi = 0$ implies $a = b = 0.$

For the third question, you can either show that $\Bbb{F}_3[i]$ is an integral domain, or you can test values of $a$ and $b.$ If $a\in\Bbb{F}_3,$ then $a^2$ is either $0$ or $1,$ and $a^2 = 0$ if and only if $a = 0.$ Thus, we have
$$
N(a + bi) = \begin{cases}0 + 0 = 0\iff a = b = 0,\\
1 + 0 = 1 = 0 + 1\textrm{ if exactly one of $a$ or $b$ is nonzero},\\
1 + 1 = 2\textrm{ if both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero}.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: We you test different values of $a$ and $b$, since the norm of $N(a+bi)\neq 0$ then we know that the norm is invertible ?

Comment: @ola Right. All elements of $\Bbb{F}_3$ are invertible except zero, so if we show the norm is only zero if we plug in 0, we have the result.